# How do I get the '<source>' of a video in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So, I'm having a problem where I want to get the video source, but it's shown as:

```
<video id="vid" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>
```

another problem is the `<source>` tag has no id, so how can I get the source of the `<source>` tag in the `<video>` tag?

Comment: document.querySelector('#vid source')

Answer (score 0):

Query for the source element inside that specific video element and get it's `src`

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#vid source').src)
```

```html
<video id="vid" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: It could have multiple `source` elements, though.